# How does matrix decomposition help fill in a sparse utility/ratings matrix for new users?

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, recommendation-engine, yelp

This is my first attempt at machine learning. I'm writing a very simple recommendation engine using the yelp dataset. It's written in python using pandas and numpy libraries for (data processing). I've already narrowed the data down first to restaurants(millions), then only restaurants in vegas(thousands), then only restaurants with 3.5 stars or higher with over 50 reviews(hundreds). Also I narrowed down the users to only those that have reviewed at least 20% of the restaurants. Finally I've arrived to a ratings matrix that has 100 users by 1800 restaurants.

However, I feel it's still to sparse to give (relatively) useful recommendations. The goal is to use item-item collaborative based filtering computing vector distance using cosine similarity.

I've been reading about dealing with sparse matrices and the consensus seems to be to use matrix factorization. It seems however that most of these readings deal with current users and use matrix factorization as the algorithm that drives the recommendation for current users while solving the sparsity issue as a by-product. Is my understanding correct here? What I'm looking for is a method that will solve the sparsity issue first and then use cosine vector distances to guide the recommendation.

If decomposition is in fact the way to go: what `sklearn.decomposition` method should I use i.e. PCA, SVD, NMF?

```
[[ 3, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 4, 3],
...
[ 1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 2],
[ 0, 0, 5, ..., 0, 1, 3]]
```

(100 Users X 1800 Restaurants)

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the amount of ratings is not a good solution to improve the accuracy of your recommendation (at least directly).
Said that, sparsity is not a "big" problem. Indeed, factorization algorithms for recommendation are designed to deal with this kind of sparsities going up to: 99%, 98%, 95% level of sparsity.

Currently, matrix factorization gives the best results and its concept is pretty simple. Moreover, memory-based CF approaches (like item-based, user-based,...) are more inefficient, less flexible and present worse results than the model-based.

**Most popular algorithms are based on SVD:**

- Funk's SVD (a.k.a SVD, although is not the real SVD. It's an approximation.)
- BRISMF (Biased regularised version of Funk's)
- SVD++: BRISMF plus implicit feedback information.
- timesSVD: SVD++ that also models the datetime
- trustSVD: SVD++ which includes trust information (like friends)

**The basics of those algorithms consists in:**

1. Create some low-rank matrices and randomly initialize them
2. For each rating in the data set, compute the error with regard your prediction.
3. Update the low-rank matrices using the gradients of the function that you are optimising
4. Repeat

**Python example (BRISMF):**

```py
# Initialize low-rank matrices (K is the number of latent factors)
P = np.random.rand(num_users, K)  # User-feature matrix
Q = np.random.rand(num_items, K)  # Item-feature matrix

# Factorize R matrix using SGD
for step in range(steps):

    # Compute predictions
    for k in range(0, len(data)):
        i = data.X[k, user_col]  # Users
        j = data.X[k, item_col]  # Items
        r_ij = data.Y[k]  # rating(i, j)

        # NOTE: For simplicity (here) I've considered the 
        # bias a standard deviation, but it should be
        # learned for better accuracy.
        bias = global_avg + std_user[i] + std_item[j]

        # Make prediction and compute error
        rij_pred = bias + np.dot(Q[j, :], P[i, :])
        eij = rij_pred - r_ij

        # Update P and Q at the same time, they're dependents
        tempP = alpha * 2 * (eij * Q[j, :] + beta * P[i, :])
        tempQ = alpha * 2 * (eij * P[i, :] + beta * Q[j, :])
        P[i] -= tempP
        Q[j] -= tempQ
```

**Extra**:

- For speed reasons (and simplicity of the code), I recommend you to have everything vectorised
- Try to create caches if needed. Accessing in sparse matrices can be pretty slow, even with the correct data structure.
- This algorithms are computationally very expensive so for simple versions you can expect to take 10s/iter in datasets of 1,000,000 ratings
- I'm building a simple library for *Orange3 Data Mining* so if you're interested you can take a look: https://github.com/biolab/orange3-recommendation